# What exactly happens when there is an exception

Tags: java, python, exception, programming-languages

This may be a very simple question,but just want to understand what exactly happens when there is an exception ,Is there a memory leak while doing operations in the memory or what is it.This is not respect to only python and java but for all programming languages

for ex:in python

```
try:
   "a"+ 1
except Exception,e:
   print "exception" + str(e)
```

Java:

```
public void FileSave(String name)
{  
   try 
   { 
      FileStream fs = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create); 
   } 
   catch (Exception)
   { 
      throw new System.IO.IOException("File Open Error!"); 
   }  
}
```

Comment: What do you mean ? Do you want to understand what is an exception, or why it is thrown, or the inner working of a exception throwing, or... ? That's not clear.

Comment: I am clear of why it is thrown..The inner working of Exception is what i want to understand

Comment: Which language are you talking about.  Exceptions tend to be very language specific.  What inner workings are you interested in as this is a very broad, complicated, but generally you don't need to know subject.

Comment: I want to know this in general or at least with respect to python and java

Comment: Try the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)

Answer (score 2):

About Java,you can get more info here : [What is an Exception?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html)

Comment: the same answer I wanna write :)

Answer (score 0):

```
i am telling you a very basic example of exception handling.
```

remember that an exception is a **RUN-TIME ERROR**, exception leads to abnormal termination of our program.

and **exception handling** mechanism ensures that, whenever any exception will occur inside our program than instead of abnormal termination, our program will follow a separate line of code and then it will terminate **normally**,

```
public void FileSave(String name)
    {  
       try 
       { 
          FileStream fs = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create); 
       } 
       catch (Exception ex)
       { 
          System.out.println(ex.toString()); 
       }  
    }
```

if the above program is written like that.

```
public void FileSave(String name)
        {  
              FileStream fs = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create); 

        }
```

and suppose that either the file does not exist or OS is not permitting for IO operations then our program will terminate abnormally, but if we use the exception handling mechanism like:

```
public void FileSave(String name)
        {  
           try 
           { 
              FileStream fs = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create); 
           } 
           catch (Exception ex)
           { 
              System.out.println(ex.toString()); 
           }  
        }
```

then when an exception will occur in code **FileStream fs = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create);**, then at first it will be checked that whether this exception will be caught in the current function or NOT, if not then **exception propagation** mechanism will be used.

refer this link. [exception handling in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/), read it carefully, you will come to know a no. of good concepts.

Comment: very nice way of describing exception handling, good concept.

Answer (score 0):

An exception occurs when a program does something anomalous – something that is not possible within the language. You can catch these exceptions and execute code to handle it. This particular piece of code is only executed when an exception occurs.

If you don't catch an exception, the execution of your program will halt.

Exceptions are very useful and many programmers expect exceptions in their code, which in turn they can catch and code around.

Compare these two examples in Python:

```
a = "foo"
b = 42

if isinstance(a, int):
    c = a + b
else:
    c = a + str(b)
print c

try:
    c = a + b
except TypeError, e:
    c = a + str(b)
print c
```

In you Java example, you are throwing a new (unhandled) exception. The program will halt, because you are not catching that exception.